# how to do the same thing that load() with xhr?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, xmlhttprequest, abort

I have this code with `load`:

```
    $('#single-photo-zoom').load(href+' #content', function() {
        alert("ok");
    });
```

I want to use `$.ajax`, but I don't know how to load `#content` in `#single-photo-zoom`

```
  xhr = $.ajax({
        url: href,
        success: function(data) {
             // ???
        }
    });
```

I would like to use `$.ajax` because I want to have the possibility to abort loading. And it's not possible with `load` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn data into a jQuery object, then can retrieve the content you want from that object and insert in appropriate element:

```
success:function(data){
    var $content=$(data).find('#content');
    $('#single-photo-zoom').html( $content);
}
```

EDIT:

assumes that `#content` is in another parent like `body` or another `div` . If not a full page and `#content` is at root level use `filter()` instead of `find()`

Answer (score 2):

Too easy if you know what load does.

```
xhr = $.ajax({
    url: href,
    success: function(data) {
         $('#single-photo-zoom').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is data here ? I would like to load `#content` in `$('#single-photo-zoom').html();`

Comment: data is the content returned by ajax call. I think charlietfl version works better